# Xcode Podfile.lock showing Visual Code Studio Logo?

Tags: cocoapods, podfile, podfile-lock

Why in the world would my Podfile.lock file be showing a VS code Logo on it? [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrzrR.png)

Comment: It seems you've set VS Code as the default app for opening files with the `.lock` extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change the default application for the .lock extension:

Right click on the .lock file -> Select 'Get Info' -> under 'Open With' select the app you want to open .lock files with.

Comment: Hey man, thank you. This worked. Could you please upvote my question? I am 4 reputation away from being able to upvote your answer lol. Thanks!